# Play audiobooks with chapter selection on iOS

Tags: ios, audiobook

I have a number of DRM free Audio Books which I listen to while walking the dog, when I put them on my iPod Classic I can scroll through the chapters and pick which one I want to listen to.

On my iPhone the file appears as a single 33 hour audio file. I'm lead to believe that this is something that has arisen since iOS7 was released, as there are a lot of threads complaining about it after upgrading.

Is there a way/third party app that will allow me to scroll through chapters, or at least carry on where I left off if I decide that I'm going to listen to music between dog walking sessions?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can use either Audiomark or Bookmobile.

Comment: Hi Klaus and welcome to AskDifferent and thanks for your answer.  Please considering improving your answer with links and description of these apps.

Comment: I couldn't get AudioMark to play, I've paid for bookmobile now though as it did exactly what I needed.